# Counting up the JSON item in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to replace the number
in lines 9 and 14 (content.card1.)
the 1 after the "card' with the
variable "i" from the for loop.
I haven't thought of anything yet.
Is that possible at all? It would
be a great help to me.

Johann

Thanks for helping!

**App.js**

```
    function App() {
      const content = require('./content.json')
      var cards = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cards.push(
          <View style={styles.card} key={i}>
              <View style={styles.TitleBox}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                  {content.card1.title}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.ContentBox}>
                <Text>
                {content.card1.content}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
        );
      }
      return(
          <ScrollView horizontal={ true } pagingEnabled={ true } showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={ false }> 
            {cards}
          </ScrollView>
      );
    }
    const styles = require('./style');
    export default App;
```

**content.json**

```
{
    "cards" : 4,
    "card1": {
        "type" : "textonly",
        "title" : "Card 1",
        "content" : "Some Text 1"
    },
    "card2": {
        "type" : "task",
        "title" : "Card 2",
        "content" : {
            "items" : 2,
            "step1" : "step1 title",
            "step2" : "step2 title"
        }
    },
    "card3": {
        "type" : "task",
        "title" : "Card 3",
        "content" : {
            "items" : 2,
            "step1" : "step1 title",
            "step2" : "step2 title"
        }
    },
    "card4": {
        "type" : "textonly",
        "title" : "Card 4",
        "content" : "Some Text 4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use dynamic keys (i.e. [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)) and generate keys `"card1"`, `"card2"`, etc. Using indices [1-4] you want to compute card numbers [1-4], i.e. `` content[`card${i}`] ``.

```
const content = require('./content.json');

function App() {
  const cards = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    cards.push(
      <View style={styles.card} key={i}>
        <View style={styles.TitleBox}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            {content[`card${i}`].title}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.ContentBox}>
          <Text>
            {content[`card${i}`].content}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return(
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    > 
      {cards}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Since you've control over the content.json I would suggest reformatting the data to be easier to render.

```
{
  "length" : 4,
  "cards": [
    {
      "type" : "textonly",
      "title" : "Card 1",
      "content" : "Some Text 1"
    },
    {
      "type" : "task",
      "title" : "Card 2",
      "content" : {
        "items" : 2,
        "step1" : "step1 title",
        "step2" : "step2 title"
      }
    },
    {
      "type" : "task",
      "title" : "Card 3",
      "content" : {
        "items" : 2,
        "step1" : "step1 title",
        "step2" : "step2 title"
      }
    },
    {
      "type" : "textonly",
      "title" : "Card 4",
      "content" : "Some Text 4"
    }
  ],
}
```

Then your code can simply map the data to JSX directly.

```
const content = require('./content.json');

function App() {
  const cards = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    cards.push(
      
    );
  }

  return(
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    > 
      {content.cards.map((card, i) => (
        <View style={styles.card} key={i}>
          <View style={styles.TitleBox}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              {card.title}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.ContentBox}>
            <Text>
              {card.content}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you can use this way.

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cards.push(
              <View style={styles.card} key={i}>
                  <View style={styles.TitleBox}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                      {content.card[i].title}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.ContentBox}>
                    <Text>
                    {content.card[i].content}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace `content.card1.content` with a dynamic variable using square bracket notation and a template literal like this:

```
{content[`card${i}`].content}
```

The template literal (backticks) allows us to concatenate the keyword `card` and the loop index `i`. The square bracket notation then allows us to use the  concatenated string as an object property reference.